# Designing an ElaticSearch cluster for massive data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, elasticsearch

I am pretty new to ElasticSearch and I am trying to use it to index document content for our users. The document content will be extracted using Apache Tika along with the file meta data and relative information (size, date, extension, etc.) and will all be stored and indexed in ElasticSearch.

The problem is that I cannot tell before hand how much data I will be indexing as this will be an added service for new clients.

What I am thinking of is to start with a single node in my cluster which will have 1000 shards and 1 replica (2000 shards in total). Each client will have his own index, this means that this node will only support 1000 clients which should be sufficient since we do not have many clients to begin with. Once the node is full we will expand the cluster and add a new node and this will extend the cluster to support 2000 clients and so on.

My concern is with the storage. Since I'll be indexing large data sets the stored data will expand rapidly in size.

For the sake of argument lets assume that I will attach a 1GB volume to my node and lets assume that I cannot expand it beyond that. Now, If I add a new node to the cluster, how will elasticsearch behave assuming the first node has already reached its storage limit (say it is now using 999MB).

If lets say client A has a new document to index and the document size is say 5MB. how will Elasticsearch behave to this? Will it move the index to the new node? or does it keep the index in the original and marks the new index request as a failure?

The reason I am asking this is because I will be hosting my ElasticSearch cluster on Amazon EC2 with an EBS volume attached to it, and since Amazon charge per provisioned GB for EBS it would be wise to start small and expand the volume when needed, so we do not have to incur massive cost at the start of the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your purposes, you need to worry about shards; 1000 shards per index is probably *insane* overkill. Each index (not each node!) consists of some number of shards and their replicas. Elasticsearch will allocate shards on nodes in your cluster automatically in an attempt to balance their distribution throughout the cluster. When disk usage reaches a configured high watermark on a node, Elasticsearch will stop allocating shards to that node. Shards can be transparently migrated to different nodes.

You can upgrade the total storage capacity of your cluster by attaching a new node with more storage. You should take care that your shard size remains small enough that it can live on a single node, but if it's too small then the overhead of managing so many shards may become prohibitive. Keep in mind that ES can query across multiple indices; a common pattern for high-volume chronological writes is to create a new index every N days, and when data is required, you run a query across all of the indexes that hold your dataset. This lets you control the size of individual indexes while accommodating significant scaling needs.

Comment: Its 1000 shards per node not index. Each index will only have a single shard and a single replica.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about setting shard maxes per node; let that be managed according to disk availability, and then maybe tweak it if you find yourself running short on RAM. Leaving your shards-per-index at a higher number, like 4-5, will help a lot in your ability to distribute your workload over time.